# Reading large binary files in small parts

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli, binaryfiles

I want to read a file from hard disk in  size up to ~4-5GB. But not whole at once but in parts of ~100MB in sequence. I want to make it simple and fast as possible, but now I see that that the standard methods from C++ will not work for files bigger than 2GB.
I use Visual Studio 2008, C++/CLI. Any suggestions? I try to use CreateFile, ReadFile but for me it makes more problems than really works, or I use them wrong for reading a big file in parts.

**EDIT**: Sample code:

**Creating handle**

```
hFile = CreateFile(result,          
                  GENERIC_READ,             
                  FILE_SHARE_READ,          
                  NULL,                     
                  OPEN_EXISTING,            
                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL     
                  |FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING               
                  | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                  0);
```

**Reading**

```
lpOverlapped = new OVERLAPPED;
lpOverlapped->hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
lpOverlapped->Offset=10;
lpOverlapped->OffsetHigh=0;
DWORD howMuchWasRead;

BOOLEAN error = false;

do {
    this->lastError = NO_ERROR;
    BOOL bRet = ReadFile(this->hFile,this->fileBuffer,this->currentBufferSize,&howMuchWasRead,lpOverlapped);
    this->lastError = GetLastError(); 
    if (this->lastError == ERROR_IO_PENDING){
        while(!HasOverlappedIoCompleted(this->lpOverlapped)){}
        error = true;
    } else {
        error = false;
    }
} while (error == true);
```

This version now returns me `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 87 (0x57)`, for 4GB .iso file, buffer size is 100MB.

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code. On windows, CreateFile/ReadFile is the only way to open files. fopen, fread is based upon those functions.

Comment: Where do you see that stdio won't support files > 2 GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file sequentially without any problems.

The limitations is that fseek uses a `long` parameter for the offset when you want to seek. If you don't reposition in the file, or the offset is always less than 2GB, there is no problem.

Comment: MS has _fseeki64 and _ftelli64 to get around this.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75yw9bf3%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: That's my fault, maybe I just don't think really clearly yesterday and forgoten that FILE remembers where it ended reading the file, so I'm not obligated to use fseek etc. So I must to use only fread.

Answer (score 3):

You can map parts of the file into the address space of your process using [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will handle files larger than 2GB, maybe you can rephrase your question so we can help you figure out the problems you are having with that.